# What is a "this-escape" warning, and how do I deal with it?

Tags: java, scope, warnings, compiler-warnings, this-pointer

I struggle to find resources on this, and yet, so many of my classes are running into this error when I compile my code on the latest Java (21).

Here is a code example.

```java
public class ThisEscapeExample
{

        public Object o;

        public ThisEscapeExample()
        {

                this.overridableMethod();

        }

        public void overridableMethod()
        {

                this.o = new Object();

        }

}
```

And here is my compilation command.

```
javac -Xlint:all ThisEscapeExample.java
ThisEscapeExample.java:9: warning: [this-escape] possible 'this' escape before subclass is fully initialized
                this.overridableMethod();
                                      ^
1 warning
```

Comment: Could someone help me with the tags? I feel like there is room for improvement there, but I can't think of what would be a better fit.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and the full compiler warning/error

Comment: Question on this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77183429/final-value-in-java-getting-reinitialized#comment136074286_77183429) yesterday

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have done so and edited the question.

Comment: @DuncG It is certainly the same source problem. Though, I think my question is useful too since it shows a more common interaction people will have with this warning.

Comment: @user85421 If you are implying a criticism of my question, I am open to hearing it. However, I don't understand your comment as is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is the JDK Bug System entry that introduces this new warning - https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8299995

Long story short, the `this-escape` warning is to warn you when a subclass may be able to `@Override` a method that is also called in the superclass' constructor.

This is dangerous because overriding a method that is used in the constructor allows subclass' to unintentionally introduce a bug during a subclass' initialization. What if that method depends on state that has not yet been created because we are still in the super constructor? After all, you cannot do anything in the subclass' constructor before calling the super constructor ([for now](https://openjdk.org/jeps/447)).

There are a few ways to remedy this.

1. Only use methods in the constructor that cannot be overridden.

   - `static` methods.
   - `final` methods.

     - MUST BE IN THE SAME CLASS AS YOUR CONSTRUCTOR, YOU CANNOT USE PARENT FINAL INSTANCE METHODS IN THE CHILD CLASS' CONSTRUCTOR
   - `private` methods.
2. Make the class itself `final`.
3. Don't pass in/use `this` to begin with - instead, pass in the particular component of `this` that you needed.

   - Basically, quit being lazy and be explicit with what you need. Don't just pass in your [God object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) -- pass in only the specific attributes you need.

Please note - these rules apply recursively. Meaning, when you call a method in the constructor, not only does that method have to be "not-overridable", but the methods that that method passes `this` into must ***ALSO*** match one of the rules above. If your top-level method is not overridable, but one of the methods inside of it is, and that method has `this` in its scope, then you will receive a `this-escape` error upon compilation. Here is an example.

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class GUI
{

   private final JFrame frame;

   public GUI()
   {
   
      this.frame = new JFrame();
   
      this.frame.add(this.createBottomPanel());
   
   }

   //final! Does that mean we are safe?
   final JPanel createBottomPanel()
   {
   
      final JButton save = new JButton();
   
      save
         .addActionListener
         (
            /*
             * No. We get the warning here at the start of this lambda.
             * The reason is because we have given this lambda the
             * ability to call this.toString(), and we don't know when
             * it will do that. Maybe now, maybe later. But if it does
             * it now, then we could end up doing things before the
             * object is fully created. And if that were to happen, then
             * that would be a this-escape. So, the warning occurs here,
             * to let you know that it is possible.
             */
            actionEvent ->
            {
           
               this.toString();
           
            }
           
         )
         ;
   
      return null;
   
   }

}
```

Comment: By the way, if you all see anything wrong with this answer, or it does not solve your problem, please let me know! This answer is getting a lot of traction, so the better my answer is, the better off everyone else is!

Comment: I have this problem and the method called (on the superclass) is final!

Comment: Post your example. If it is long, ask a new question, and I will edit this answer to show it off as an example.

Comment: @AlessandroPolverini And if you do make a new question, send me a link to it.

Comment: @AlessandroPolverini Please ignore my previous comments. I see the problem. I need to add more detail to my answer. Please see my edited answer and tell me if that clarifies where the issue is.